# How do I view newest unanswered questions with a specific tag in new interface, with the mouse?

Tags: support, tags, sorting

Not sure if this is just SO or elsewhere but there's a new interesting looking tab interface (I guess this is part of the "new" site navigation, maybe I'm late to the party here -- I haven't answered questions on SO in a while although I don't remember it being like this the last time I was there):

[image]

My question is: With the new interface, how can I view new, unanswered questions in one of my favorite tags using only my mouse? I used to be able to do this by clicking my favorite tag then clicking one of the sort tabs. Now, "newest unanswered" and "favorite tag" seem to be mutually exclusive unless I type the tag in the "newest unanswered" filter box every time (despite already having a tab for that tag).

When I try the old way now (click tag in side bar "favorites" list → click "newest"), clicking the tag takes me to the tag tab, but then clicking "newest" resets the view to *all* tags with an empty filter box, instead of retaining the tag I was looking at.

There's a drop down on the tag tab but it looks like it's tab edit actions only:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons to the left and right of the "tag filter list" allow you to specify more options for the tab.

On the left, the filter icon lets you specify which questions you want to see, including unanswered ones:

[image]

The arrows icon on the right lets you specify the sort order, e.g. newest first:

[image]

Once you've set the options how you want, save the tab and it will remember them for the future:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Lots of drop downs to learn. I just assumed that button would toggle ascending / descending for some reason and didn't check it.